# NASM compilation on DOSBox

Tags: assembly, nasm, dosbox

I'm trying to link some assembly files, but I'm having some problems. I use nasm and I make my object file with:

```
nasm program.asm -f bin -o program.exe
```

Code from book

```
    %include "io.mac"

.DATA
name_prompt db "Please type your name: ",0
out_msg db "Your name in capitals is: ",0

.UDATA
in_name resb 31

.CODE
    .STARTUP
    PutStr name_prompt ; request character string
    GetStr in_name,31 ; read input character string

    PutStr out_msg
    mov EBX,in_name ; EBX = pointer to in_name
process_char:
    mov AL,[EBX] ; move the char. to AL
    cmp AL,0 ; if it is the NULL character
    je done ; conversion done
    cmp AL,’a’ ; if (char < ’a’)
    jl not_lower_case ; not a lowercase letter
    cmp AL,’z’ ; if (char > ’z’)
    jg not_lower_case ; not a lowercase letter
lower_case:
    add AL,’A’-’a’ ; convert to uppercase
not_lower_case:
    PutCh AL ; write the character
    inc EBX ; EBX points to the next char.
    jmp process_char ; go back to process next char.
done:
nwln
    .EXIT
```

This code work for me at Windows XP but not work at Windows 7, here is error log
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnqan.jpg).Please help me find error.

Comment: Those quotation marks look suspect. They should probably be `'` rather than `’`. And make sure that the macro file is found by the assembler.

Comment: io.mac is located in file with nasm and program.asm, but i do not know how check assembler find this file.

Answer (score 1):

The line numbers in the error messages appear to refer to the macros. Nasm would complain if it didn't find the `%include` file, so it's finding "io.mac", but isn't liking it. As a WAG, it looks like the late Dr. Sivarama Dandamudi's stuff... you should have "io.obj" which you link against, right?

You're assembling into Nasm's "-f bin" output mode, which produces a flat binary file - not a linkable object file. The "-o" switch causes the output file to be named ".exe", but it's still a flat binary file, not an ".exe" nor a linkable object file. I strongly suspect that you should be assembling to "-f obj" or "-f win32" and linking with... some linker... What did you do when it worked? I'll guess "-f obj" is what you want. You probably don't need the "-o" switch - the default filename should be okay.

If all else fails, you can try the "-e" switch (preprocess only). This won't produce any useful output, but will just expand the macros. This won't solve any problems, but will let you see exactly what Nasm's complaining about. You shouldn't have to do this!

Despite the fact that it uses a 32-bit register, this may be 16-bit code (yeah, you can do that). The difference between XP and 7 is that 7 won't run DOS code. DosBox should take care of that for you (if all goes well). Try assembling to "-f obj" and see what that does for you. Once you get Nasm to "shut up and assemble", we can go on to getting it linked and running...